# Python type hint for specific values of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am a fan of `mypy` and I would like to add some type hints on a dictionary that has different type of values.

My dictionary is the following

`{'name':'John', 'age':136, 'hobbies':['Python', 'cooking', 'reading']}`

The current typing I think of is: `Dict[str, Union[str, int, List[str]]`

Is there any way to specify that `name` is a string, `age` is an integer, and `hobbies` is a list (for further specific type checking by `mypy`)?

**NOTE:** This data is coming from an external source containing a list of such objects. I have a limited control over it, except looping through the elements and converting them.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you are looking for an Object, not a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 3.8, check out [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), "a dictionary type that expects all of its instances to have a certain set of keys, where each key is associated with a value of a consistent type. This expectation is not checked at runtime but is only enforced by type checkers."

The following passes type checking:

```py
from typing import List, TypedDict

Person = TypedDict("Person", {"name": str, "age": int, "hobbies": List[str]})
p: Person = {"name": "John", "age": 136, "hobbies": ["Python", "cooking", "reading"]}
```

But this doesn't:

```py
from typing import List, TypedDict

Person = TypedDict("Person", {"name": str, "age": int, "hobbies": List[str]})
p: Person = {"name": "John", "age": 136, "hobbies": [42, "cooking", "reading"]}
```

Error:

```
main.py:4: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be an instance of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

My suggestion would be to use a class for that, instead of a Dictionary. This is precisely what they are made for.

Comment: Agree on that. It was part of a Python challenge I was doing. I was actually transforming into an object. Great minds think alike.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. That can be simplifed into a `namedtuple`.

Comment: @Sraw Indeed... Actually it was a lit of them so I transformed into a Panda Dataframe :)

Comment: This answer is outdated. [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) was introduced in Python 3.8 for this exact problem.